# How to handle schema in hibernate native SQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I am setting the default schema in hibernate in a spring boot application as shown below :

```
properties.put(""hibernate.default_schema, "myschema");
```

Do I have to put the schema again in SQL

```
select col1, col2 from myschema.table
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to access schema, if you have configured in datasource creation in Hibernate config.

```
select col1, col2 from {h-schema}table;
```